# SQLAlchemy delete on cascade is slow. Can i improve performance without Circumenventing the ORM?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, cascading-deletes

### I am building a flask application with an sqlite database at the backend.

I attached a picture of the database structure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecf0h.png)

At this point i only ever load one file of data into the database. All fields in all tables can be traced to a common root container representing the whole data of the file. Now to delete the data it is the easiest to simply set up cascade_on_delete in the database then delete the root container, letting the database do the rest.

I did set up the relations accordingly, i also implented the event.listener for turning the Pragma Foreign_keys = On on every connection as described in the sqlalchemy documentation.

When I delete the data via root_container like this it takes 27seconds:

```
root_container = db.session.get(Container,root_container_id)
db.session.delete(root_container)
db.session.commit()
```

However Deleting via database Console by simply using SQL takes about 1 second:

```
Delete From Container Where id = root_container_id
```

I can pass this through the ORM by executing the raw SQL and get the same performance:

```
db.session.execute(f"Delete From Container Where Container.id = {self._root_container_id}")
```

This works and performs as quickly as the Console command. I dont feel like this is best practice and wonder if i can achieve the same perfomance without circumventing the ORM? It seems like the ORM is loading a lot of objects in the background but i dont know how to disable that.

Database Structure

[[image: Database Structur]]

Answer (score 1):

It seems always the same, after 3 days of searching the net i write a question on stackoverflow, only to find the answer 3 hours later.

The reason for the slow performance is a standard behaviour of the ORM that ignores the cascade on delete on the database level and instead tries to resolve everything on the ORM level loading every object into memory and therefore taking ages to perform the deletes. The answer is to set the *passive_deletes* flag to true when you define the relationship.

The proper way to implement a working cascade on delete in sqlalchemy with sqlite which uses the underlying database is as follows.

1. In the Model set up the foreign key column with cascade on delete

   ```
   class Parent(db.Model):
      id=db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
      children = db.relationship('Child', cascade="all,delete,delete-orphan", passive_deletes=True)

   class Child(db.Model):
      id=db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
      parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer(),db.ForeignKey(Parent.id, ondelete='Cascade)
   ```

The db.ForeignKey argument in the Child Table defines the ForeignKey and cascading behaviour on the database level. Meaning you can find it in the sql-definition of the create table statement.

The children db.relationship object defines the relationship on the ORM level. The passive_deletes Flag is False by default, meaning in a cascading deletion it will first load all relevant objects into memory and delete through the ORM layer. When you set it to true, it will pass the deletion through to the Database level. This ignores then the cascade="all,delete,delete-orphan" argument.

2. Dont forget to Set up the event listener which enables the Foreign_keys in SQLite on every connection.

   ```
   @event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
   def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):        
        cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=1;")
        cursor.close()
   ```

I hope this helps for others who struggle with the intricacies of SQLAlchemy and SQLite.